# ¿Cómo realizar correctamente una herencia de clases en Python?

Tags: python, poo, herencia, class

> Buenas tardes a todos:
>
> Estoy empezando con la POO de Python y en el curso que estoy siguiendo
> nos piden que realicemos un programa que asigne e imprima en pantalla
> las asignaturas, profesores y estudiantes de una universidad.
>
> Para ellos nos han pedido definir:
>
> - Una clase superior *Miembro* con **nombre, edad y dni** como atributos
> - Dos clases que hereden de ella: **Profesor** (con número de registro y asignaturas que imparte como atributos y dos métodos, añade docencia
>   e imprime docencia) y **Estudiante** (con número de estudiante como
>   atributo)
> - Otra clase **Asignatura** con nombre, código y estudiantes como atributos, método añade estudiante y método imprime listado.
>
> Tengo que usar los datos que me han dado que son:
>
> Profesores:  Luis, 50 años, dni 34567 y número de registro 5001 Pepe,
> 37 años, dni 65432 y número de registro 5010
>
> Estudiantes:  Jorgito, 20 años, dni 56678, número de estudiante 1001
> Juanito, 19 años, dni 4444, número de estudiante 1002 Jaimito, 19
> años, dni 22334, número de estudiante 1005
>
> Asignaturas:  matemáticas, código 5, impartida por Luis física, código
> 5, impartida por Luis latín, código 13, impartida por Pepe historia,
> código 19, impartida por Pepe filosofía, código 36, impartida por Pepe
>
> Relaciones de matrículas:  matemáticas > Jorgito física > Juanito y
> Jaimito latín > Jorgito y Jaimito historia > Juanito y Jaimito
> filosofía > Jaimito
>
> Este es el código al que he llegado:
>
> '''
>
> class Miembro():
> def **init**(self, nombre, edad, dni):
> self.nombre = nombre
> self.edad = edad
> self.dni = dni
>
> ```
> class Profesor(Miembro):
>     def __init__(self, nombre, edad, dni, registro):
>         Miembro.__init__(self, nombre, edad, dni)
>         self.registro = registro
>         self.asignaturas = []
>
>     def añade_docencia(self, asignatura):
>         self.asignaturas.append(asignatura)
>     
>     def imprime_docencia(self):
>         print("Las asignaturas que imparte", self.nombre, "son", self.asignaturas)
>
> class Estudiante(Miembro):
>     def __init__(self, nombre, edad, dni, num_estudiante):
>         Miembro.__init__(self, nombre, edad, dni)
>         self.num_estudiante = num_estudiante
>
> class Asignatura():
>     def __init__(self, nombre, codigo):
>         self.nombre = nombre
>         self.codigo = codigo
>         self.estudiantes = []
>
>     def añade_estudiante(self, estudiante):
>         self.estudiantes.append(estudiante)
>     
>     def imprime_listado(self):
>         print(self.estudiantes, "está matriculado en", self.nombre)
>
> luis = Profesor("Luis", 50, 34567, 5001)
> pepe = Profesor("Pepe", 37, 65432, 5010)
>
> jorgito = Estudiante("Jorgito", 20, 56678, 1001)
> juanito = Estudiante("Juanito", 19, 44444, 1002)
> jaimito = Estudiante("Jaimito", 19, 22334, 1005)
>
> matematicas = Asignatura("matemáticas", 5)
> fisica = Asignatura("física", 7)
> latin = Asignatura("latin", 13)
> historia = Asignatura("historia", 19)
> filosofia = Asignatura("filosofía", 36)
>  
>
> luis.añade_docencia([matematicas, fisica])
> pepe.añade_docencia([latin, historia, filosofia])
> filosofia.añade_estudiante(jaimito)
> filosofia.imprime_listado()
> pepe.imprime_docencia()
> ```
>
> '''
>
> Pero esto es lo único que consigo:
>
> ''' [<**main**.Estudiante object at 0x00C47460>] está matriculado en
> filosofía Las asignaturas que imparte Pepe son [[<**main**.Asignatura
> object at 0x00C474F0>, <**main**.Asignatura object at 0x00C47520>,
> <**main**.Asignatura object at 0x00C47550>]]
>
> '''
>
> ¿Alguien me podría echar una mano para comprender dónde tengo mal el
> código?
>
> ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: La class Miembro también sería código:  
class Miembro():
        def __init__(self, nombre, edad, dni):
            self.nombre = nombre
            self.edad = edad
            self.dni = dni

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Por que mi los items de mi lista no tienen nombre string?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/333371/por-que-mi-los-items-de-mi-lista-no-tienen-nombre-string)

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer más corta la explicación, revisemos este caso:

```
class Ejemplo:
    def __init__(self, contenido):
        self.contenido = contenido

ejemplo1 = Ejemplo("Asado")
print(ejemplo1) => <__main__.Ejemplo object at 0x7efefea6fe80>
```

¿Tienes un objeto y quieres imprimirlo? Tienes que especificar cual es su representación como cadena definiendo el método mágico `__str__` en la clase:

```
class Ejemplo:
    def __init__(self, contenido):
        self.contenido = contenido

    def __str__(self):
        return self.contenido

ejemplo1 = Ejemplo("Asado")
print(ejemplo1) => Asado
```

Como su nombre lo sugiere, `__str__` debe retornar una cadena legible.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!
También lo he intentado haciendo un loop y no ha quedado mal.